# Reuse current app instance when clicking on Notification

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

Right now I'm using a `PendingIntent` to launch my desired `Activity` from the `Notification`. But I want to know if it's possible to reuse the current app instance.

For example:

- Launch app, the Launcher Activity is called `HomeActivity`
- Navigate to `SecondActivity`
- Press the home button
- Click on the notification from the app and resume `SecondActivity`

But if the user didn't navigate to the `SecondActivity` i want to open the `HomeActivity` when I click on the Notification. I would be glad for any help regarding this problem :)

Comment: in pendingIntent you will pass an intent, so in that normal intent you should set a flag like `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` so if the app is in background it will just bring activity to front.

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to know if it's possible to reuse the current app instance.

Yes, you can reuse if the app is in background. In **PendingIntent** you will pass an **Intent**, so in that **Intent** you should set a flag like `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` so if the app is in background it will just bring activity to front.

According to android docs :

> **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**
>
> Added in API level 1 int FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK If set, this activity
>   will become the start of a new task on this history stack. A task
>   (from the activity that started it to the next task activity) defines
>   an atomic group of activities that the user can move to. Tasks can be
>   moved to the foreground and background; all of the activities inside
>   of a particular task always remain in the same order. See Tasks and
>   Back Stack for more information about tasks.
>
> This flag is generally used by activities that want to present a
>   "launcher" style behavior: they give the user a list of separate
>   things that can be done, which otherwise run completely independently
>   of the activity launching them.
>
> When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity
>   you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started;
>   instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the
>   screen with the state it was last in. See FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK
>   for a flag to disable this behavior.
>
> This flag can not be used when the caller is requesting a result from
>   the activity being launched.

Check the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

> But if the user didn't navigate to the **SecondActivity** i want to open the **HomeActivity**.

Why do you launch **HomeActivity** if your notification intent class you are creating have **SecondActivity** as the launcher. It will create a new **SecondActivity** and launches it if it is not in background.

**EDIT:**
 If you want to relaunch app where you left off try like this :

```
final Intent resumeIntent = new Intent(context, YourLauncher.class);
resumeIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN"); 
resumeIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"‌​);
final PendingIntent resumePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resumeIntent, 0);
```

Here `YourLauncher.class` is the launcher class name.

Comment: I wanna know if there's a possibility to have the same functionality when i click the notification as I have in the app switcher, just reenter the app wherever i left it.

Comment: You can use `intent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");` and `intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");` for launching the app where you left off.

Comment: `final Intent resumeIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");

 resumeIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");

final PendingIntent resumePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resumeIntent, 0);`

this doesn't work for me

Comment: @finki check my edit.

Comment: Yeah, still not resumes the app where i left it. But thx for your effort :)

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with your code, but i tested it by creating a sample and it works gud.

Comment: so if u start your app, open another activity, press the home button and then click on the notification your another activity opens and not your launch activity?

Comment: yes it is just bringing app to front where you left off during home button press.

Comment: what's your launch mode for both the launcher and second activity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130957/discussion-between-akshay-bhat-and-finki).